# how to create multiple chart is my data is coming into xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, charts, highcharts

I m creating a html and call the xml file and create throw a line chart and now my problum is that

how to create multiple chart as like i want to create this data three chart

1. pie
2. line
3. column
4. line is by default show but i want to pie and column char my data is coming into xml file

i m useing this [**api key**](http://www.highcharts.com/)

NOw i search this solution in net but i m not finding solution i found **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/74uwhtsn/)**

But here is data is static in javascript how to this

My Real **[Data link is this](http://plnkr.co/edit/YiNkpi1KqkUFtYM0q8dK?p=preview)**

My code is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="highcharts.js"></script>

        <script>

          // Code goes here
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* *********************************************************** */
  /* *********************************************************** */


  var newOPtion4 = {

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'lineChart4',
      type: 'line',
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
        stops: [
          [0, 'rgb(255, 240, 255)'],
          [1, 'rgb(240, 255, 240)']
        ]
      },
      borderWidth: 1,
      plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)',
      plotShadow: true,
      plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Salary Chart Last 8 Years',
      style: {
        color: '#000',
        font: 'bold 16px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#000',
      tickColor: '#000',
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#000',
          font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
      },
      title: {
        style: {
          color: '#333',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'

        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      alternateGridColor: null,
      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      lineColor: '#000',
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickWidth: 1,
      tickColor: '#000',
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#000',
          font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Month Salary',
        style: {
          color: '#333',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      itemStyle: {
        font: '9pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
        color: 'black'

      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#039'
      },
      itemHiddenStyle: {
        color: 'gray'
      }
    },
    credits: {
      style: {
        right: '10px'
      }
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#99b'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: {
          duration: 3000
        },

      }
    },
    series: []
  };

  // Load the data from the XML file 
  $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {

    // Split the lines
    var $xml = $(xml);

    // push categories
    $xml.find('categories item').each(function(i, category) {
      newOPtion4.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
    });

    // push series
    $xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {
      var seriesOptions = {
        name: $(series).find('name').text(),
        data: []
      };



      // push data points
      $(series).find('data point').each(function(i, point) {
        seriesOptions.data.push(
          parseInt($(point).text())
        );
      });

      // add it to the options
      newOPtion4.series.push(seriesOptions);
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(newOPtion4);
  });
  /* *********************************************************** */
  /* *********************************************************** */

});
        </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="lineChart4" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;   margin:0 auto"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In these lines:

```
  var seriesOptions = {
    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
    data: []
  };
```

You are creating series. If you add this:

```
  var seriesOptions = {
    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
    data: [],
    type: 'column'
  };
```

Then you will create column series. Now if you add 'type' property in each of series (like 'name' above), then use that property for series type.